# Como adicionar um header personalizado no AJAX com javascript puro?

Tags: javascript, ajax, web-service, header

Estou utilizando javascript puro para enviar um AJAX com o header Access_token com uma key dentro, pois o web-service pede essa requisiçã... mas não está indo como eu gostaria.

Quero que fique assim:

[image: Ajax como eu quero]

Mas Está ficando assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue minha função:
    function funcao(){

```
var xmlhttp;

if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}else{
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){

    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;

    }
 }

  xmlhttp.open("POST","https://www.asaas.com/api/v1/customers?name=Lucas",true);
  xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Access_token', 'bdb4b600eee96f16bf118c617a65561eba06629525c07f6564b9531a38959468');
  xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = handler;
  xmlhttp.send();

 }
```

Comment: De qual browser você está tentando? O domínio do seu aplicativo é o mesmo do recurso solicitado? E por último, você poderia disponibilizar o source da requisição e da resposta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo que vi os headers estão sendo passados corretamente, notei que quando você recebe algum código que não seja do tipo 2XX, por exemplo 401, 404 ou outros o chrome exibe os cabeçalhos desta forma:

[image: Requisição 401]

Desta forma os cabeçalhos ficam listados no Access-Control-Request-Headers, mas seus valores não são exibidos.

Usando a mesma função contra um servidor que aceita, com os mesmos cabeçalhos nós já recebemos uma resposta diferente, do jeito que você quer como na imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Neste caso acredito que você não esteja vendo do jeito que quer por causa do servidor, e não por causa de sua implementação de AJAX.

Mesmo na questão de navegadores levantada pelo Rui Pimentel a sua implementação está normal, tanto no IE(7+) quanto nos outros navegadores se usa o método setRequestHeader(header, valor) para alterar ou adicionar headers as requisições.

A documentação do método está disponível em:

- MDN -> https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#setRequestHeader()
- MSDN -> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536752(v=vs.85).aspx